# WriteFile() and ReadFile() asynchronously not writing or reading

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to send and receive strings across a serial port connection using the `writefile` and `readfile` functions. I have to do this asynchronously because the number of bytes to read will always be different and `readfile` will just hang or block until it gets those correct number of bytes. Now that I'm trying to do this asynchronously my `writefile` function won't send any data and my `readfile` function just appears to be skipped because the next line begins doing it's thing without any characters being read. Not sure if it's a problem with my Overlapped structure or my timeouts. But I'm stuck at this moment.

Timeouts

```
void Serial::OpenPortRead()
{
HANDLE sSerial =  CreateFile(L"COM3",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,0);
//Timeout Settings
COMMTIMEOUTS    CommTimeouts;   
GetCommTimeouts(sSerial, &CommTimeouts);
CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout            = 5000; 
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier     = 2; 
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant       = 10; 
    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier    = 50; 
    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant      = 500; 

//Port Settings
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_19200;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

SetCommState(sSerial,&dcbSerialParams);//Apply Settings to Handle




}
```

Write file function

```
void Serial::WritePort(CString buffer)
{


DWORD bytes;//pointer to hold number of bytes written
USES_CONVERSION;
CW2A buf((LPCWSTR)buffer);//Convert unicode to ascii



OpenPortRead();
OVERLAPPED overlapped_structure;
memset(&overlapped_structure, 0, sizeof(overlapped_structure));
overlapped_structure.Offset = 0;
overlapped_structure.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

WriteFile(sSerial, buf,strlen(buf),&bytes,&overlapped_structure);//Send string


}
```

Read file function

```
int Serial::ReadPort(CString buf){

OpenPortRead();// Open Serial Communication for reading

const int buffer_size = 10;
 char buffer[10];//buffer to hold recieved string

memset (buffer, 0, buffer_size * sizeof (char));
int n, num,iTemp,i=0;
OVERLAPPED overlapped_structure;
memset(&overlapped_structure, 0, sizeof(overlapped_structure));
overlapped_structure.Offset = 0;
overlapped_structure.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

DWORD bytesRead;//pointer to number bytes read


ReadFile(sSerial,&buffer,buffer_size,&bytesRead,&overlapped_structure);// begin read



//Used this function because return would be filled with extra raw data characters
buffer[n] = StringLength(buffer, &n);//find length of string returned
num = n;
```

Comment: After WriteFile/ReadFile you need to wait for overlapped event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but maybe an example to help me out

Comment: The point of overlapped I/O is that it completes *later* and your program can keep running while it is in progress.  Waiting for it completely removes the point of using it in the first place.  Whatever your problem might be, overlapped I/O isn't the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN contains detailed information about how to use overlapped I/O with serial port communications:

[Serial Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)